Crypto Asset Claim Redemption Dashboard
We are looking to create a Claim/Redemption dashboard system using SAFE as the programmatic asset custodian, where an external user of our application can "claim" or request for the transfer of the asset from our SAFE wallet (which we would programmatically send/approve).
A requirement is for the external user to pay the gas fee for transfer.
What would be the proper method to pass the gas cost of this transaction onto the user?
Thank you,
Adam

In a normal context, this means the user would have to propose the transaction, and then the owners of the safe would need to confirm it. There could be ways to automate that but it might not be the most straightforward way.
Another way would be to use a custom module that your users would directly call. Modules can bypass owners confirmation, so it would make the flow simpler, and also make the users bear the cost of the transaction.
Did that answer your question? Best, Louis

Thanks Louis! Seems like this puts us on the right track!  I have some questions from our devs: When we confirm the transaction proposed by the user, the user can then sign by himself? Does the user need to get permission to propose that transaction? Could that be permission be given automatically/programmatically? Thank you

Happy to help! Yes, if you write your own module, you can set it up in a way where either (i) anybody or (ii) only users that appear on a whitelist could propose transactions. This logic would be handled by the module itself. Best, Louis
